# How do i pull last element from a set of nodes?

Tags: jquery, dom

Im using jQuery to get a list of nodes; using an each() statement, im trying to pull the last element from a set of nodes that are visible after some event (specifically, the last node id).

Using each and is(":visible") i can get all nodes visible, how can i extract/pull the last element of this set?

I've tried .last() and .get() without success

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" id="inicio-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#inicio" role="tab" aria-controls="inicio" aria-selected="false">
       <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
       <span class="labelTab">Inicio</span>
     </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" id="como-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#como" role="tab" aria-controls="como" aria-selected="false">
       <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
       <span class="labelTab">Como</span>
     </a>
</li>

<script>

$(".nav-link").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(":visible")) {
            var i = $(this).attr("id");
            $(i).get(-1); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

This doesn't get me the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the `.last()` method to get the last element.

```js
var lastVisibleNavLinkId = $(".nav-link:visible").last().attr("id");
```

Does that work?

Update: I think you can use the `:last` selector, also.

```js
var lastVisibleNavLinkId = $(".nav-link:visible:last").attr("id");
```

Comment: Correct! i was mistaken using each, i can get a set of all elements without it using, as you comment correctly, .last(), and apply manipulation on it. Thank you for clarify!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.